# How to join multiple column on one?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been trying to get counts of data on subgroup for each month. There is a column named subgroup in questions table and also there is sdate column which holds insert date. I want to get all subgroup counts on months. So i can see how many data inserted on some month for per subgroup.

I have this query so far and this works for 1 subgroup. I want to add other subgroups to it.

```
SELECT all_months.month "Month", COUNT(QUESTIONS.SUBGROUP) AS FI
            FROM(SELECT LEVEL AS month FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) all_months
LEFT OUTER JOIN QUESTIONS ON(all_months.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SDATE) AND 
SUBGROUP='FI' AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SDATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)) 
GROUP BY all_months.month ORDER BY "Month" ASC;
```

This query returns this:

[image: result]

and this is what i want.

[image: what i want]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT all_months.month "Month", 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN QUESTIONS.SUBGROUP = 'FI' THEN 1 END) AS FI,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN QUESTIONS.SUBGROUP = 'G1' THEN 1 END) AS G1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN QUESTIONS.SUBGROUP = 'G2' THEN 1 END) AS G2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN QUESTIONS.SUBGROUP = 'G3' THEN 1 END) AS G3
FROM ( 
   SELECT LEVEL AS month 
   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) all_months
   LEFT OUTER JOIN QUESTIONS 
     ON(all_months.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SDATE) AND 
     SUBGROUP IN ('FI', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3') AND 
     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SDATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) ) AS t 
GROUP BY all_months.month 
ORDER BY "Month" ASC;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you sir :)